# Would 2 100k Ohm resistors provide the same as a 200k ohm in series?

Tags: resistors, resistance

Practically what it says in the title. I would also like to know if it would emit more heat and would the tolerance be higher?.

Comment: Instead of me saying yes/no it is much more eductional if you just take the formulas you know (I hope), 1) ohm's law: V = I x R and 2) for power dissipation (not heat, you probably mean power: P = V x I. Now assume a voltage, 100 V for example and calculate all parameters for each case (2 x 100 k and 200 k). For tolerance, make all resistors 10% lower and see what you get.

Comment: @FakeMoustache thank you for you comment/answer. if you were to make this an answer i would certainly mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two 100K resistors in series will give you a value of 200K. The differences are:

1. Total heat dissipation is the same but now spread over a larger area. This is only an issue if you have temperature sensitive components nearby. These would be items such as voltage references, thermal fuses, etc.
2. Breakdown voltage is doubled. This is important if they are use to bleed the charge off a high-voltage capacitor, or the 'X' capacitor across the AC mains in power supplies. In which case it is not unusual to see 4 100K resistors in series to have at least a 50% safety margin.
3. Temperature drift is an accumulative error, so multiple resistors in series or parallel will drift by the value of one resistors drift times the number of resistors in series or parallel. Not recommended for precision voltage dividers or fixed gain control.
4. If accuracy is the primary concern, buying a single 1% or even .1% 200K resistor will yield the best results.

Comment: The tolerance will remain the same 1%. In fact, it will be better, on average, but worst case will still be the same as using one resistor.

Comment: @pipe. The tolerance per resistor is 1%, but errors in each resistor accumulate. I'm assuming worst case errors that add in the same direction. Granted that this is splitting hairs considering how accurate and stable metal film resistors can be. The teachers I had 40 years ago put a lot of junk into our heads that has little meaning today.

Comment: I suggest you do the simple calculations to see that this is not true. 1% higher than 100k is 101k. 2*101=202. 202k is still 1% higher than 200k.

Comment: @pipe. I see your point, at least for 2 resistors. Will correct answer.

Comment: Temperature drift can be looked on in the same way as tolerance. That is, if one resistor drifts 1% because of a change in temperature, then the total resistance two resistors in series, or parallel will drift by the same percentage if both drifts are equal and in the same direction .

Comment: @EMFields. I agree with your logic, which means that 4 resistors or more in series runs a slight risk of being out-of-tolerance, unless they were .1%. I have never seen more than 4 smd resistors in series, and that was to bleed off the charge on the 'X' capacitor on the AC line, so they were likely 5% at best.

Answer (score 2):

> Would 2 100k Ohm resistors provide the same as a 200k ohm in series?

Yes, a series connection of two 100 kΩ resistors will give 200 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhjh3n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Series connection. (b) Parallel connection.*

**Series connection**

$$ R_{total} = R_1 + R_2 + ... $$

**Parallel connection**

$$ \frac {1}{R_{total}} = \frac {1}{R_1} + \frac {1}{R_2} + \frac {1}{R_3} + ... $$

> I would also like to know if it would emit more heat ...

Heat dissipated will be the same but spread across two devices.

> ... and would the tolerance be higher?.

Tolerance won't be worse and *may* be better.

- If the 100k resistors were 99k each then they are -1%. Series connection would give 198k which is -1% of 200k.
- If the resistors were 99k (-1%) and 101k (+1%) the series connection would be 200k giving a 0% error. In practice you might find that resistors from the same batch tend to have the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Two 100k resistors in series would behave exactly the same as one 200k resistor, emitting the same amount of heat under the same conditions.

If the two 100k resistors were 1% tolerance, then the worst case deviation of the 200k resistor would also be 1%. However, the distribution of values of a collection of 200k resistors would be tighter than that of the component 100k resistors.